# Multiple colourpickers within splitLayout, colour box gets hidden

Tags: r, colors, shiny

When two colour pickers used side by side using *splitLayout*, colour map gets hidden. It might be easily fixed using `tags$style...HTML()`, any ideas?

- Link to *colourpicker* package: [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=colourpicker) and [GitHub](https://github.com/daattali/colourpicker)

Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(colourpicker)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      splitLayout(
        colourInput("PlotThemeColour1",
                    "Plot theme shade 1",
                    "#C2C2C2"),
        colourInput("PlotThemeColour2",
                    "Plot theme shade 2",
                    "#E5E5E5"))),
    mainPanel(textOutput("myCols"))
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$myCols <- renderText({
      paste(input$PlotThemeColour1, "and", input$PlotThemeColour2)

    })
  })
```

---

#### Output

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the right way of fixing it. But a quick workaround is to override the css that's causing it. Currently the value of that css `.shiny-split-layout>div`'s `overflow` is set to `auto` and this is present in `shiny.css` so using an inline css to override it with `overflow:visible` seems to solve the issue.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(colourpicker)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
     tags$style(HTML('.shiny-split-layout>div {
                         overflow:visible;
                                   }')), 
    sidebarPanel(
      splitLayout(
        colourInput("PlotThemeColour1",
                    "Plot theme shade 1",
                    "#C2C2C2"),
        colourInput("PlotThemeColour2",
                    "Plot theme shade 2",
                    "#E5E5E5"))),
    mainPanel(textOutput("myCols"))
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$myCols <- renderText({
      paste(input$PlotThemeColour1, "and", input$PlotThemeColour2)

    })
  })
```

Approach #2:

Using `cellArgs` of `splitLayout` to override individual cell css.

```
library(shiny)
library(colourpicker)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    sidebarPanel(
      splitLayout(
        colourInput("PlotThemeColour1",
                    "Plot theme shade 1",
                    "#C2C2C2"),
        colourInput("PlotThemeColour2",
                    "Plot theme shade 2",
                    "#E5E5E5"), cellArgs = list (style = "overflow:visible"))),
    mainPanel(textOutput("myCols"))
    ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$myCols <- renderText({
      paste(input$PlotThemeColour1, "and", input$PlotThemeColour2)

    })
  })
```

Comment: Thank you that is what I was hoping for. I will keep the question open, in case there are other ways to achieve this without using `tags$`.

Comment: @zx8754 Very glad I could help. Also added a second approach.

Comment: Great, `cellArgs` is the way to go for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`splitLayout` has `cellArgs` which can hold your overflow:

```
library(shiny)
library(colourpicker)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      splitLayout(cellArgs = list(style = "overflow: visible;"),
        colourInput("PlotThemeColour1",
                    "Plot theme shade 1",
                    "#C2C2C2"),
        colourInput("PlotThemeColour2",
                    "Plot theme shade 2",
                    "#E5E5E5"))),
    mainPanel(textOutput("myCols"))
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$myCols <- renderText({
      paste(input$PlotThemeColour1, "and", input$PlotThemeColour2)

    })
  })
```

Comment: Sorry didn't see your answer before posting my Approach #2

Comment: Yes, thank you, `cellArgs` is what I was looking for, worked as expected.